# Pandas Updating/Merging DataFrames not by Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
df1
        col_1
0     0.135824
1     0.179398
2     0.222971
3     0.266545
4     0.310119
...        ...
2955  0.859648
2956  0.885337
2957  0.911026
2958  0.936715
2959  0.962404

[2960 rows x 1 columns]

df2
           col_1
    57     -0.28
    58     -0.29
    59      -0.3
    60    -0.315
    61     -0.32
    ...      ...
    21439 -0.335
    21440 -0.325
    21441  -0.32
    21442 -0.315
    21443 -0.325
    
    [3034 rows x 1 columns]
```

I'm looking to update df2 with values from df1. With the differences in rows amount, I would like to skip the first 74 rows of df2 and update from the 75th row (index 383).

The desired output would be something like this:

```
df2
           col_1
    57     -0.28
    58     -0.29
    59      -0.3
    60    -0.315
    61     -0.32
    ...      ...
    21439 0.859648
    21440 0.885337
    21441 0.911026
    21442 0.936715
    21443 0.962404

   [3034 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: do you mean something like this? df2['col_2'] = list(df2['col_2'])[:75] + list(df1['col_1'])[75:]

Comment: Unfortunately that raises a ValueError since the length of values does not match the index.